# Why does bootstrap switch not appear in same line as other elements in the div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have the code below:

```css
.global-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header {
  width: 1024px;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.contents svg {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.contents .title {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.contents .switch {
  align-content: right;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="global-wrap">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="contents">
      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="white" class="bi bi-list" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
                    </svg>
          <span class="title">Title</span>
          <span class="form-check form-switch">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Text</label>
                    </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the bootstrap switch does not appear on the same line as the hamburger and Title Text. Why doesn't bootstrap element appear on a new line and how can I make sure that the switch appears on the same line being right aligned?

Comment: your `form-check` class is getting `display: block` property that's why it is in the new line...you can either remove that class or add new property according to your requirements

Comment: your parent span (class form-check form-switch) is marked as "display:block" so it will take up its own line. Suggest you replace this with `display inline-block;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `d-inline-flex` class to the `form-check` class. Also, add the `position-absolute` class to the `form-check` class and the `position-relative` class to its parent. Finally, add the following CSS to align the switch right:

```
.form-check.form-switch {
  right: 0px;
}
```

See the snippet below.

```css
.global-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header {
  width: 1024px;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.contents svg {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.contents .title {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.contents .switch {
  align-content: right;
}

.form-check.form-switch {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="global-wrap">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="contents">
      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group d-flex align-items-center position-relative">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="white" class="bi bi-list" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
                    </svg>
          <span class="title">Title</span>
          <span class="form-check form-switch d-inline-flex position-absolute">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Text</label>
                    </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the `.form-check` class is displayed as a `block`, which means in regular flow it moves to its own line.

To create an *inline* form check, use the `.form-check-inline` class along side the `.form-check` class.

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#inline

```html
<span class="form-check form-check-inline ...">
  ...
</span>
```